# Reset Doctrine ResultSetMapping for subsequent query

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, nativequery

I'm using Doctrine2 in Zend Framework 2. In a very unique case, I need to create a native SQL query which only selects a table's id and does some geographic calculations. I followed the documentation and created a ResultSetMapping definition for this query:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Location', 'l');
$rsm->addFieldResult('l', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('distance', 'distance');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT l.id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(:lat))
        * cos( radians( l.latitude ) )
        * cos( radians( l.longitude ) - radians(:lng) )
        + sin( radians(:lat) )
        * sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
    FROM location l
    WHERE
    l.latitude BETWEEN (:lat - .2) AND (:lat + .2)
    AND l.longitude BETWEEN (:lng -.2) AND (:lng + .2)
    HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance'), $rsm);
$query->setParameter('lng', $lng)
    ->setParameter('lat', $lat)
```

This returns a result set correctly and I process it.

However, I want to return a fully hydrated collection of those entities so I do a simple DQL query

```
$em->createQuery('SELECT l FROM Location l WHERE l.id IN (:locations)')
    ->setParameter('locations', $locationIds)
    ->getResult();
```

The resulting collection of entities only  has the 'id' field hydrated. All other values are null.

I suspect this is because I set the ResultSetMapping for the previous query and it's being applied in the DQL afterwards as well. How do I go about resetting Doctrine's mapping behavior back to default?

**Edit**

Here is a truncated version of the Location entity. It hydrates just fine in all other areas of the site.

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="location")
 */
class Location extends RestrictedSite
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @Annotation\Exclude()
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, name="name")
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $latitude;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 *
 * @var float
 */
protected $longitude;


... more columns & methods ...
}
```

The schema is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Please paste your Location entity as well as your mapping

Comment: I've edited the original post to include a basic example of what the location entity looks like and its corresponding table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it in the doctrine docs here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html

I need simply invoke `$em->clear();` to reset the mapping and the full entity is hydrated in the subsequent DQL. Yay!